# Then nothing / meaning in context

Tags: meaning

I was watching the movie "when harry met sally " and I had a trouble to understand this highlighted part of their conversation. Thank in advance.

> Sally : I'd like the pie heated and I don't want the
>   ice cream on top I want it on the side and I'd like strawberry instead
>   of vanilla if you have it if not then no ice cream just whipped cream
>   but only if it's real if it's out of a can ***then nothing***.
>   Waitress: Not even the pie?
>   Sally: No, just the pie, but then not heated.
>   Waitress: Uh huh.

Answer (score 2):

Sally doesn't want whipped cream unless it's real whipped cream, not 'dairy product' out of an aerosol can.

If the 'whipped cream' is out of a can (she says) then she wants nothing. That's ambiguous, prompting the waitress' question: does 'nothing' mean literally *nothing*—no whipped cream or ice cream **and no pie**, either—or just *no whipped cream*? Sally assures her she means the latter.